# Change the installation based on the OS language in Wix Installer

Tags: wix, registry

I have been using Wix installer to create the installer and the installer register a port during the installation (using netsh.exe). Everything is working fine.  But then I tried to install the application on a Windows 7 OS which is French...the installer could not register the port because the netsh command was written for en-US.
The following command works fine on en-US machine:
**netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http: //+:6700/Demo101/ user=\users** but fails on fr-FR OS.

For fr-FR I needed to run 
**netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http: //+:6700/Demo101/ user=\utilisateurs**

I made the following changes in Wix project:

```
<?define langLocale = [OSINSTALLEDLOCALE]?>


<?if $(var.langLocale) = "00000409"?>
<!-- Firewall exception -->
<CustomAction Id="ListenerServiceAddReservation"
              Execute="deferred"
              Impersonate="no"
              Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
              ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http://+:6700/Demo101/ user=\users"
              Return="asyncWait" />
<?else?>
<CustomAction Id="ListenerServiceAddReservation"
          Execute="deferred"
          Impersonate="no"
          Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
          ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]netsh.exe http add urlacl url= http://+:6700/Demo101/ user=\utilisateurs"
          Return="asyncWait" />
<?endif?>
```

But this is not working becuase it does not get the value "00000409" and always goes to else condition which is for French and machine is in en-US.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use localized Wix Properties (Custom actions) to resolve correct name, see doc: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/osinfo.html (site is down right now so i can't confirm the correct link) or google WixQueryOsWellKnownSID

In you example i assume you are referring to "users" group so to get it working add a PropertyRef

```
<PropertyRef Id="WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS"/>
```

Then in your Custom Action use `[WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS]` property which will resolve to correct group name for built-in Windows users and groups.

```
<CustomAction Id="ListenerServiceAddReservation"
              Execute="deferred"
              Impersonate="no"
              Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
              ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]netsh.exe http add urlacl url=http://+:6700/Demo101/ user=[WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS]"
              Return="asyncWait" />
```

With this you won't need to have different Custom Action for different locale.

Answer (score 1):

The `<?if?>` and `<?else?>` statements are preprocessor stuff, they are resolved at compile time.  That won't work.  The key here is that the SIDs for built-in users and groups are constant, so you need to use [S-1-5-32-545](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en-us).

In WiX v3.10/v4.0 and later, you can use the [WixHttpExtension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/http/):

```
<http:UrlReservation Url="http://+:6700/Demo101/">
    <http:UrlAce SecurityPrincipal="*S-1-5-32-545" Rights="register" />
</http:UrlReservation>
```

Using netsh:

```
netsh.exe http add urlacl url= http://+:6700/Demo101/ sddl= "O:BAG:BAD:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-32-545)"
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. Where to get the WixHttpExtension? How to add in the project. I tried this xmlns:http="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/HttpExtension" but it doesn't recognize UrlReservation.

Comment: @Vijay It isn't available until v3.10/v4.0, which are both still in development.  You can find weekly builds at http://wixtoolset.org/releases/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [IlirB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331719/ilirb)

the issue is resolved. very little change in the script:

instead of **user=\[WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS]** it should be ***user=[WIX_ACCOUNT_USERS]***